# Cannot deserialize JSON object when using Json.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

I send the following body with HTTP request serialized by Json.NET:

```
{"parties":[{"name":"Name","number":"Number"}]}
```

WebService checks whether there is a list of "parties" objects or just a single object. And depending on results of this check list of objects or single object is returned. And in situation with the body I provided I receive the following exception:

> Test 'WebService.Tests.Tests.Post_create' failed: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize JSON object into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[JSON.WebService.Parties]'.

Is there any solution for such problem?

Updated:

Here is the Parties type:

```
public class WebRequestBody : JSONBody
{
    public List<Parties> parties { get; set; }
}

public class Parties : JSONBody
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
}
```

Web Service is waiting exactly for such a body :(

JSONBody is a class that describes serialization and the structure is too deep to copy it here. But if it is needed I can share it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to tell without seeing the type of `Parties` and your JSON decoding code, but I'm guessing that you don't need the entire message you're sending. You might just need this:

```
[{"name":"Name","number":"Number"}]
```